# Is there any way to download all google Webfont's in all formats?

Tags: web-scraping, font-face, webfonts, google-webfonts, progressive-download

First of all i am well aware [of this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273210/any-place-to-get-google-webfonts-in-all-formats) and i have a strong feeling that it was closed because it was asked by a google critic.

My sub-question is: Am i right to assume that the processing that is described [here](http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/wiki/HowToGenerateWebNativeFonts) is done **after** the ttf creation meaning it would not be possible to just batch convert them all together? If please tell me how (on linux)

*Even if it would prefer the actually files google serves rather then having web services or tools convert them because google might done this the absolute best way possible!*

I have some feeling that there is something out there, somewhere. Because it *maybe* just needs a script that changes the browser referrer and asks google http responses, downloads them and renames them to names based on the 'local' fontname in the css. In addition some web scraping to the the font names and the possible variation (bold/normal/...)

This is why i am trying this again in addition to that: I am a web Programmer i need this for my localhost web development so this is a this is a perfectly valid question for Stack Overflow in my mind  and i am sure many have the desire to get hands of all fonts an easy way. So please at least migrate it somewhere it you think its not a valid question!

Comment: The suggested solution "Converting TTF to web formats isn't all that hard" seems invalid to me, especially if i want to convert 500 fonts. Additional i want to say that i perfectly understand that the person, asking the other question about this, explained in details why he wants to download them. Because it's really annoying on Stack Overflow there are always people who ask way, implying that it's stupid or useless to have a particular goal, because they can't see it from another perspective then their own. Yes it was a bit a rant, but still there was this valid question inside it.

Comment: I tried doing this once by adding every font to my "collection" then click "download your collection". It told me that I was not able to download that large of a file. It seems like I can typically download about 7 font families at a time.

Comment: Well even if this would work the fonts in that package would still be only .TTF! Getting them **should** be easy: just hg clone [this](http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/source/checkout)

Comment: I would try to get a single font in all formats one by one and watch which urls are submitted for each request. Determine the rules. Perhaps only the extensions differ. Then clone the TTF fonts from http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/source/checkout. Write a script to walk through the directory, create the request urls and wget.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the list of available fonts from https://fonts.google.com/metadata/fonts. Then use [goog-webfont-dl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/goog-webfont-dl) to download all the formats of each font. I used the command `cat ~/fonts.txt| while read line; do goog-webfont-dl -a -f $line;done` to download each font in the list. Here is a [gist with all the fonts up to 2016-07-12](https://gist.github.com/sanbor/f65b5b014a4fdcdc3346a8fcfd800886).